# Ask to pass on advice to another person?

Tags: recruitment

I've been in contact with a recruiter who has provided me some fantastic advice on working in a specific industry, what links I should use to apply etc.

However, he has mentioned that he does not handle recruitment for the specific role I am looking for.

How do I ask him, politely without offending, that you could if you have time to pass on my details and be able to ask for advice to someone who actually handles the recruitment for these roles?  Cause saying 'Can you please pass my details onto someone who actually does the recruitment' sounds a bit rude!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It might be more appropriate to ask if he *knows* anyone who's recruiting for that industry type.  This may result in him passing on your details, or directing you to an agency that he's familiar with.

If you're the one to engage the other recruitment agency, at least you know the message has got there (otherwise, you're left wondering "did he pass my details on?" if you don't hear anything).

Comment: Yes, and don't worry: networking is what recruiters do all day long.  It's not at all out of place to make a request like this.  (They would be quite happy to ask you if you know any people suitable for a position).